# Maya Rendered images, camera matrices

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, rendering, maya

I have some rendered images from Maya, What I like to have is extrinsic and intrinsic matrices as you would get from the calibration of a real camera. I've extracted the rotation and translation but I can't figure out the intrinsic matrix. I found is the projection matrix but it doesn't work the same way. I want to be able to convert between world coordinate to pixel coordinate like this: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is looking for an answer, I found this link useful: https://github.com/chloelle/MayaCamera. It converts Maya camera attributes to OpenCV camera matrices.